# Why is finviz not showing some stocks?

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, trading, stock-markets

Finviz is a popular stock screener and is recommended by many traders. However, when I put a filter of ["shorted more than 30 percent"](https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sh_short_o30),
it did not show me GME whose short percent is higher than 30 [as seen here](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/gme).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two web sites disagree then clearly one of them is wrong.

Given that Gamestop is a heavily shorted stock, FINVIZ is incorrect (GME doesn't even display for at >5% shorted).

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that SEC could fine websites for showing incorrect data. 

I notice that ticker info on finviz[https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=GME] does not even show publicly available short percentage. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I am unaware of a rule that the "SEC could fine websites for showing incorrect data".  If this were true, we'd all be rich from the errors that we find at Yahoo Finance and even the broker Robbing By Hoods :->).  I too was surprised that FINVIZ didn't display the short percentage. GIGO programming?